# Minor gripe: My flags are helpful, my spam flags are Helpful

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Perhaps spam flags are slightly more helpful than normal flags and deserve capitalisation?

Comment: I will hereafter use this report to legitimize my pluralization bugs.  See?  There *is* something less important! Upvoted, though, that is kinda annoying and without a vertical column, it's already hard enough to scan the list.

Comment: @Kevin I would argue that pluralization bugs have a lower importance:complexity ratio. :)

Comment: Gentlemen, please, let's not argue. The important thing is that Jeff is going to set fire to both your homes in due time.

Comment: All of your flags are equally helpful.  But some of them are [more equal than others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm).