# I'm not gaining flag weight for my Spam flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-weight

Often my Spam flags never get marked as '[Helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108465/minor-gripe-my-flags-are-helpful-my-spam-flags-are-helpful)', even after they are deleted:

[image: Wonderful Spam]

Bill the Lizard, JNK and I carried out a little experiment to check, and I do not receive an increase in flag weight when this occurs, although the same does not apply for offensive flags.

Comment: ...did you check your flag weight?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I will try, but I've still got a few pending atm.

Comment: Ok, I've got one outstanding flag (it's actually offensive not spam). Hopefully it will be deleted without being marked helpful and I can see if my flag weight changes...

Comment: I deleted that post without marking the flag as helpful (for science).  Can you check now to see if your flag weight changed?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Science fail, it is marked as Helpful (and my flag weight has increased).

Comment: I wonder if spam and offensive flags are treated differently when a post is deleted without explicitly marking the flag.

Comment: Possibly. Can't see any more spam flags for the moment, I'll look again later (though there are *hundreds* of non-answers, the limit on flagging is extremely annoying!)

Comment: Do you want to just post an answer here on this question and flag it as spam so we can test it?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Another fail, I can't flag my own post as Spam! Someone else do it? (P.S. this won't negatively affect my account will it?)

Comment: As long as only one person flags it you shouldn't see any negative effects.  You took my last comment so  literally that I'm afraid to ask you to post and flag something offensive for comparison.  ;)

Comment: No change in flag weight after marking it as spam.

Comment: It didn't get marked as helpful either.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Interesting. Should I retag this as a bug do you think?

Comment: Related: [What determines the outcome of a spam/offensive flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107296/what-determines-the-outcome-of-a-spam-offensive-flag). I did watch my flag weight, and only those marked helpful affected it.

Comment: @fredley After discussing this with other moderators, it looks like it's by design.  I'll post an answer with details.

Comment: Is this related to why spam flags were "Helpful" whilst other flags are "helpful"?

Comment: sounds like a bug - adding to my list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a bug here; it *was* processing things that were "flagged for moderator attention" (i.e. bespoke messages), but it was not processing the spam/offensive flags. This is because back in the depths of time (before we explicitly tracked flag outcomes), such votes on **deleted** posts were ignored in the moderator-facing UIs. It looks this didn't get updated to explicitly process the outcomes when the community votes to delete a post.

This has been fixed in the code (and will be deployed next release, usually within a day), and I will try to apply the change retrospectively.

Comment: So is/was the bug here that post deletion doesn't dismiss red flags, or that a moderator agreeing with them doesn't trigger post destruction, with rep penalty and all that?

Comment: @lunboks in related to the scenario where it was deleted by voting

Comment: Great.  Will this still deliver the -100 rep penalty when something is spam?

Comment: @MatthewRead yes, this is unrelated; the rep penalty is to whoever posted it; the credit that was missing was to the people who flagged it as spam

Comment: Right, cool.  I suppose that just means we have to be really careful to dismiss a spam flag before deleting if "Not An Answer" or such applies instead.

Comment: It seems the change *was* applied retroactively -- my number of helpful spam flags on tex.sx has increased from 6 to 10 (out of a total of 15).

Answer (score 25):

It looks like this is a behavioral issue on the part of moderators.  There are actually four actions we can take with spam flags:

- Marking it helpful. This increases your flag weight without deleting the post.
- Marking it unhelpful. This decreases your flag weight.
- Just deleting the post. This does not affect your flag weight.
- Reflagging it as spam ourselves.

A moderator reflagging a post as spam will delete the post *and* increase everyone's flag weight who flagged it, so it seems that that's the option we should be using when we agree with spam flags.

Comment: Is this a naming issue with the options on the mod console then? (I.e. would it be better if the options were renamed to (Agree/Disagree/Just Delete). I don't see the point in having 'Mark as Helpful' without deleting the post too.

Comment: @fredley: Yeah, a few of us were a little bit puzzled by that too.  I guess "helpful" is supposed to mean that we don't necessarily 100% agree that the post should be removed, but we want to encourage you to keep flagging the way you are.  In my mind deleting really should be tacit agreement with the flag, but having more options does give us finer control over the outcome.

Comment: If you delete a post that was brought to your attention by a flag, isn't the flag helpful by definition? Even if the post was really "not an answer", the "spam" flag still alerted you to it.  I agree that fine control is good, but the *default* for deleting a flagged post should be marking the flag helpful.  It should be dismissed before the deletion if that case ever comes up.

Comment: Flagging as spam also shows the post deleted by "Community" rather than the moderator and gives the post another down-vote - both of which are a "good thing".

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, I agree.  That's what I'll be doing from now on, it just doesn't make sense that the flag isn't automatically marked helpful when I delete the post.

Comment: @fredley - There's the opposite case too where the flag is helpful but the action wasn't a delete (e.g. editing post/sin-binning account)

Comment: And when the devs want to run stats on how much spam there is and what is coming through, deleted posts bring that true number down in a bad way. Non answers aren't spam so shouldn't be handled, flagged or removed in the same way. @mat

Comment: @random Makes sense, except that dismissing a flag and then deleting the post anyways creates a void of information about the real reason, similarly affecting the stats badly.

Comment: This sounds like a bug; I can see this is going to be fun to re-apply retrospectively

Comment: I think the main reason why #4 isn't commonly done is that there's no "flag as spam" option from the flag queue. You actually have to click through to the post to flag it as spam.

Comment: @waiwai933 Yes, exactly.  It's much easier to just delete from the mod queue if I can see that it's spam.

Comment: @Bill can I add a fifth option to that pile - which is to just destroy the owning user without directly interacting with the post or flags (which I sometimes do on SU if they're a one-post spam user, for example) - if deleting doesn't, then I suspect this also probably doesn't confer any flag weight.

Comment: @DMA57361 Yeah, I can see how that might happen.  If I look at their posts and quickly see that they're 100% spammer, I might destroy the account without clearing flags.

Comment: @ChrisF Really? Just noticed that the deleted spam post on this thread is shown as deleted by Bill the Lizard.

Comment: @fredley - probably because Bill deleted it rather than flagging it as spam.